# Object doesnt collide

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody body;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        body.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        Debug.Log("Collision");
        Destroy (this);
    }
}
```

AS you can see this has an `OnCollisionEnter` however my object is unable to Collide with anything instead it flys through every object?

This is my `prefab`:

[image]

And the object im trying to collide with:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: Why your Sphere is a trigger? Disable trigger and it should be ok

Comment: Sadly that did not work either :(

Comment: You might also want to consider using `RigidBody.AddForce()` or other physics methods to move you object - if you use `Translate()`, it will move it without paying attention to physical interactions, and could cause some missed collisions.

Comment: @Serlite ive updated my code could you have a look. it is still not triggering the collision

Comment: You should also ensure your Rigidbody is *not* kinematic, or it won't figure into the physics simulation.

Comment: Do you check this link before ? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/917922/unity-5-oncollisionenter-not-working.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `isTrigger` you need to check the collision with `OnTriggerEnter`. If you want to use the `OnCollisionEnter`try adding a `rigidBody` to the cube with the `is kinematic` (for performance) flag, disable the `is trigger` from the sphere and see if that works.

Check the difference of the methods here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Regards

Comment: Have you debugged your application? Debug your game and manually move one object to the other on the `Design View` so you can see both colliders overlapping and see if your code fires. Also, try to add a box collider to it just for testing purposes, (you can leave your sphere collider there, just disabled it) and check if the script fires.

Comment: Just one of the rigid bodys should be kinematic. Not both of them btw